# TinyDB, storing multiple lists in TinyDB, split stored data in tinyDB

Tags: mysql, app-inventor, storing-data, tinydb

I am making an app with **App Inventor**, which calculates runners time and position, and store this data in **TinyDB**. This data is displayed on screen as well. Now the point comes to post it to my server and the problem comes here. I have displayed data in a procedure so that it should be displayed in columns form rather than in single line, but now **I am not getting how to post the data in the same procedure to my server**.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

[https://programming-with-app-inventor.googlegroups.com/attach/3faf95954e4b06ef/screenshot.png?view=1&part=4](https://16071421899061906419.googlegroups.com/attach/3faf95954e4b06ef/screenshot.png?view=1&part=4).

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add an example of the format your server accepts. Also a screenshot of the relevant App Inventor blocks could help.

Comment: there are two columns of db on server position and time and data should be uploaded in them vertically i tried to solved this problem by procedure , and procedure worked but now the problem is that i am not getting how to upload procedure to server .please see the screenshot.

Comment: oo oo this stackoverflow is not allowing me to post screenshot .i am new here now tell me how to show screenshot?

Comment: `there are two columns of db on server position and time and data should be uploaded in them vertically` this sounds like you are talking about a MySQL database on your server? **Please edit your question instead of adding more comments**, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for screenshots, load it up somewhere and provide a link to that screenshot here... you have to work on your reputation, see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation...

Comment: You successfully edited your question, great! Now: are you talking about a MySQL database? Or what is the data format your server accepts? Try to find that out... Also take a look at the [stock quotes tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/stockquotes.html) how to work with the web component... and, as already mentioned: don't forget to work on your reputation ;-)

Comment: yes the database behind is MYSQL , and it accepets the data pased to two columns in the way . like e.g in querystring name1=value1 & name2=value2 . , so in that i want to pass list of entries. like right now i have two options to do either to submit result one by one by submitting each entry from phone emmulator or submit whole list. and i am wishing to submit list thatsy i am trying to call the procedure along with querystring rather than the single value

Answer (score 0):

> yes the database behind is MYSQL , and it accepets the data pased to two columns in the way . like e.g in querystring name1=value1 & name2=value2

You can use the web component to post your data to the server. The query string you can generate inside your existing procedure. Then just use the following 2 blocks to post your data:

```
web1.Url = <your url>?name1=value1&name2=value2
web1.PostText = <empty string>
```